# Facebook how to find different types of facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I was looking into the page table and they have a "type" field in there which  categorizes what type of page it is.

There are different values like "TV SHOW", "Book" , "Public Figure" , "Movies" etc

Is there a way I can query or find out the complete list of all different types of categories of pages available.

Thanks

Comment: all other types means? All other types means types except above mentioned or all other means all types?

Comment: No I mean what are the different types of pages - like I've mentioned a few "TYPES" above - where can I get the complete list of these "TYPES" - Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gublooo: You can visit this url for complete list of page type:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types